# YouTube API: Costs for a higher quota?

Tags: youtube-api, google-cloud-platform

I need a higher daily quota for the Google API / YouTube API.

So I want to sign up for the free trial, but I can't seem to find any costs for that in the Google Cloud: https://cloud.google.com/pricing/list

Am I missing a major part here?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question and I didn't find a price list. When you enable a Youtube Data API in your google console you can go to section quotas for this API and set quota to value from 1 to 1 million. If you need more, you should do a manual request to Google through filling a special form, accessible by a link.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find the Quota Usage for Youtube API

[Youtube Quota Usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota on the [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/quotas) tab in the Developer's Console.

You can calculate the quota [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)